# In grails, how to do I test where queries with associations?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I am tying to test a [where query](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries) but it always returns an empty list. If I remove the `owner.name == "Jane"` the query returns something, but when I put it back, it wont return anything anymore. The `where` query definitely works with basic model searches on test-app but, I'm not sure if it works when associations are included. It works ok on `run-app` though, it just seems to fail on test-app. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to mock something? I am using grails 2.3.9 and spock. Note: I am doing a unit test.

```
 Owner owner = Owner.build(name: "Jane")
 Pet expectedPet = Pet.build(breed: "Random dog", owner:owner)

 when:
 def pets = Pet.where {
            breed == "Random dog" && owner.name == "Jane"
 }.list()

 then:
 pets.size() == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I am able to pass your test, however, with my own domains. My assumption is you might have other fields in your domains that are causing the `save` to fail. My suggestion is to use `buildWithoutSave` and save it yourself with `failOnError:true` to debug it further.

Hope it helps

// Spec:

```
import grails.buildtestdata.mixin.Build
import spock.lang.Specification

@Build([Owner, Pet])
class OwnerSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        setup:

        //Owner owner = Owner.build(name: "Jane")
        //Pet expectedPet = Pet.build(breed: "Random dog", owner: owner)

       Owner owner = Owner.buildWithoutSave(name: "Jane")
       owner.save(failOnError: true)

       Pet expectedPet = Pet.buildWithoutSave(breed: "Random dog", owner: owner)           
       expectedPet.save(failOnError: true)

        when:
        def pets = Pet.where {
            breed == "Random dog" && owner.name == "Jane"
        }.list()

        then:
        pets.size() == 1
    }
}
```

//Domains

```
class Pet {

    String breed
    testsave.Owner owner

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Owner {
    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, my owner object is way more complicated than what I revealed. It has several fields that refers to other objects. I was wondering if I should just mock the return values of the "where" clause just to get it over with, but I guess that would defeat the purpose of the test. I have that "where clause" in my service btw, if that's significant. :(

Comment: In a bigger picture the current tests is really testing Grails and build-test-data functionality. I would not worry much about testing them. As you said probably focusing on core business and mocking unnecessary processes is better approach unless there are some business logic or application related logic in being tested.

Comment: Yeah, I was just testing it out because the where clause didn't return anything. I wanted to see for myself if the where clause was working on tests. I was wondering, do you know how to mock where queries? I tried to do the metaClass thing, but it didn't work.. Do you think, something like `Pet.where() >> expectedPets` should work? I don't think the where clause is a method though. I'll try it out when I get home. edit: I'm not even sure if it's a method, a closure or what. lol